# How can I do a column check while running INSERT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I want to INSERT a number of rows in a table CARTON with columns ID and STATUS. Where I want to check if the STATUS value is not 'CLOSED'. If it is 'CLOSED' then ignore the query and move on, if it is not then go ahead and INSERT the row.
P.S. I can't add check or any constraints on the table.

I want to do something like this:

IF status in ('OPEN', 'IN_PROGRESS') then INSERT into carton(id, status) values(1, 'OPEN')
ELSE - move to the next query.

Please suggest your solutions.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, if its Oracle you can make use of Insert all/first

Comment: (1) The scenario lacks information. If you know the value to insert in advance, why not  put the logic to not insert in your application? (2) Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic using Insert all in Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_STATUS(ID INT, STATUS VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT ALL
    WHEN STATUS <> 'CLOSED' THEN
    INTO TEST_STATUS VALUES(ID, STATUS)   
    SELECT 1 ID, 'CLOSED' STATUS FROM DUAL;
    
INSERT ALL
    WHEN STATUS <> 'CLOSED' THEN
    INTO TEST_STATUS VALUES(ID, STATUS)   
    SELECT 2 ID, 'PENDING' STATUS FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle is the case as DB, the syntax

```
INSERT WHEN ... THEN INTO target(col1,col2,col3)
SELECT col1,col2,col3 
  FROM source
```

might be directly used such as

```
INSERT WHEN status != 'CLOSED' THEN INTO carton
WITH source ( ID, status ) AS
(
 SELECT 10, 'OPEN' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 20, 'IN_PROGRESS' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 30, 'CLOSED' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 40, 'OPEN' FROM dual 
)
SELECT * FROM source
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ab763660a9ceafb80a4b9f5f2e2e423)</kbd>